# Client thinks a certain feature is included in the price, but it isn't

Tags: contracts

My client hired me to build an iPhone app. The contract states that the app has to work on all iPhones that can run iOS8 or higher. He just sent me an email asking why he cannot install it on his iPad. I think he didn't really understand that iPhone doesn't include iPad, when he signed the contract.

How do I tell him politely, that he will have to pay more for adding iPad support to the app?

It may be important to know that he hasn't paid the full amount yet.

Comment: Clients often need additional tutoring from your side. Do spend extra 10 sentences so he understand the difference. You will also know if he is really confused or looking for free work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're interested in the additional work, I would cite the original agreement and state that you're willing to create a new contract for this additional work (including a few examples of where things need to be adapted for iPads). I'd also ask to schedule a phone call to talk through the issue, to make sure he understands the distinction and issues, but also that you're willing to work toward getting the app working on iPads, too. (If he's already frustrated/confused by this scenario, an actual phone or in person chat can prevent him misreading your tone in an email.) Make sure you have a ballpark figure in mind (in terms of compensation and/or hours) before getting on the phone, though, as I would expect that to be one of his first questions.

Answer (score 2):

What impact is there for you to compile the app for ipad? If its not so much effort, I would do it with the understanding that its on best effort basis support.

Secondly, for future contracts, you need to ensure there is an "in scope" and an "out of scope" section to ensure clarity.

Find a compomise to enhance your chance of getting paid without problems and also the chance of winning future work/changes to the existing product.

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding of end users that creating an iPad app is just a case of compiling the iPhone code with iPad as the target. The reality is that to make a good iPad version can take weeks of extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Explain him that just because the two products belongs to the same brand doesn't mean your app will have to work in both of them and you developed it for the iPhone, as stated it in the contract. However, if he/she needs it working in the iPad, tell him/her that you will charge an **extra amount**. I would charge an extra amount and not the same prize (or more) this time, because of two reasons: first, I'm not an expert, but I guess you can use the main part of your existing code for the iPad app development and second, this teaches you to ask for better specifications in the future, specially when the client hasn't got a technical background.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the old "Feature X is not in scope" may be called for. Explain that there is an additional effort in making an app iPhone AND iPad compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others have mentioned, the iPad was out of scope.  You can communicate that fact, and if you are able, make modifications as such.

BUT.... get your money for the current work BEFORE you do anything that's out of scope.  You're less likely to get burned.